# Capture VGA Port

Tags: hardware, video, vga

I have implemented an FPGA program in Verilog which outputs a video signal over an VGA port. When I hook it up to a monitor via VGA it works great and the image is displayed on the screen.

I am now wondering how I can capture the output of this VGA port from my FPGA. Is there a way to reverse the VGA port on my GNU/Linux laptop (Arch Linux) such that I can capture a signal coming in, as opposed to outputting a signal?

If not, what are my options for capturing (recording) this VGA signal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VGA (as in the standard 15-pin DE-15 connector, etc.) Isn't reversible. It's a uni-directional signaling line.

You'd need something like a VGA "[frame grabber card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_grabber)" or "VGA2USB" adapter, as it is sometimes called. Those are specifically VGA inputs (presenting themselves to whatever is connected to them as the control board of a monitor, essentially). They're available as USB dongles or pigtails.

Same thing is true for most other video ports, including all variants of DVI.